# Issue with generate_matching_address function in bit library by ofek

Tags: python, bitcoin

I've been using bit library by ofek (https://github.com/ofek/bit) to generate specific bitcoin addresses with generate_matching_address.

Here's my code:

```
from bit.keygen import generate_matching_address
generate_matching_address(prefix='111')
```

The result was:

```
WIF: 5JWehNgDymMXJKS9GfpVWqasYHWcvvCSvWAYCu9EZ1Gkx8sdrVC
Address: 111M7AsA62ynkXXoeUWgqtKhpbpyFxNrY
```

But when i tried to use generated WIF to import key with this code:

```
key = wif_to_key('5JWehNgDymMXJKS9GfpVWqasYHWcvvCSvWAYCu9EZ1Gkx8sdrVC')
print(key.address)
```

I got this output:

```
12mWYMcDUMtxG6617gEHpBHiCtpPdL92hL
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `111` address is compressed, while the `12m` is uncompressed. They both are generated from **the same private key**.

---

However, it seems there is a bug in the `generate_matching_address()` function.

Correct WIF for `111M7AsA62ynkXXoeUWgqtKhpbpyFxNrY` (compressed) address is `KzHsPCg8HYmajSMyWALcrhSW55sjayoXR9j6jX9LpGCYz96x6cXW`. While the output (`5JWehNgDymMXJKS9GfpVWqasYHWcvvCSvWAYCu9EZ1Gkx8sdrVC`) is WIF for the **uncompressed** address `12mWYMcDUMtxG6617gEHpBHiCtpPdL92hL`